# Why parfor is slower than for when accessing 3-D array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing, parfor

I want to make my for loop run faster in a program that i use a 3-D array and by experimenting i came to the conclusion that when I access a 3-D array with parfor is slower than doing it in for, whereas when I run the same code but using a 2-D array the results are the opposite.
A small example is the following.

```
**%Storing data on 3-D array with parfor** 
tic
parfor (i=1:100)
    for (j=2:2134)
        for(x=1:1000)
    k(i,j,x)=100;
    end
    end
end
toc
Elapsed time is 319.463914 seconds.

**%storing data on 3-D array with for**
tic
for (i=1:100)
    for (j=2:2134)
        for(x=1:1000)
    k(i,j,x)=100;
    end
    end
end
toc
Elapsed time is 25.601181 seconds.

**%Storing Data in 2-D array with parfor**
tic
parfor (i=1:1000)
    for (j=2:2134)
        for(x=1:1000)
    k(i,j)=100;
    end
    end
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.774042 seconds.

**%Storing Data in 2-D array with for**
tic
for (i=1:1000)
    for (j=2:2134)
        for(x=1:1000)
    k(i,j)=100;
    end
    end
end
toc
Elapsed time is 3.060670 seconds.
```

I am running in with 4 workers when in parallel.
Why is this happening when I am using 3-D arrays and how can i solve it?

Comment: You're not storing arrays of the same size and there's a lot of reallocation going on in the 3d case. In fact, if you're running the script exactly as you have it here, your first loop is allocating **all** of the memory for the 3d array. I'd try comparing arrays with the same number of elements and preallocating.

Comment: You need to preallocate, as beaker said, and you also need to loop in the right order: when indexing `k(i,j,x)`, put the loop over `x` as the outer loop, and the one over `i` as the inner loop. Finally, make sure you configure the parallel pool to work multithreaded, rather than the default multi-process (where arrays are copied to other instances of MATLAB for processing).

Comment: Finally, when timing, put your code inside a function and run the function. This typically leads to faster times, especially if you run the function a second time.